# Best practice when checking multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors, coding-style

Is there a better way **(Cleaner Code)** to check multiple variables which have the same check.

```js
const var1 = $("#var1")
const var2 = $("#var2")
const var3 = $("#var3")
const var4 = $("#var4")
const var5 = $("#var5")

  if (
    var1.length === 0 ||
    var2.length === 0 ||
    var3.length === 0 ||
    var3.length === 0 ||
    var5.length === 0
  ) {
    alert('Not all elements have been added :( ');
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having many numeric-indexed variables in the first place is often an indicator that you should have an array instead. Instead of

```
var var1 = ...
var var2 = ...
```

do

```
const arrays = [
  ...,
  ...,
  // ...
];
```

Then you can refactor your condition to

```
if (!arrays.every(array => array.length > 0)) {
    alert('Not all elements have been added :( ');
    return;
}
```

Remember that arrays are 0-indexed, so this will mean that what used to be `var1` will now be `arrays[0]`, and so on.

Comment: you could also do `[var1, var2, var3, var4].every...` if the original `var` are really needed - also, I'd use `array.some(array => array.length === 0)` - personal choice :p

Comment: The variables I'm grabbing are DOM elements, would this work?

Comment: no it would not @SamMWoods ... suggest you use `[var1, var2, var3, var4].every...`